# Joomla 2.5 Adding submenu to Component manifest

Tags: joomla, manifest, submenu

Im trying to add the `<submenu>` and some language files into a joomla 2.5 component manifest but even after i add them there is no change in the admin panel like the new manifest never got loaded.

Can you tell me how to make the component use the new updated manifest file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you just modifying the manifest on the server or are you reinstalling the component?
Because the menu is only created during component installation.

Comment: Yes im just modifying. So the only way is to uninstall and reinstall the component?

Comment: Don't uninstall, just install over the existing one. If you set the method in the extension tag to "upgrade", this is possible. Like this:
<extension type="component" version="2.5" method="upgrade">